# Send mail to your gmail account inbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a form in which if we submit input the the value of this input shows in your in box,So far i achieved this,After i click on submit it open a google pop up,Thanks in advance

```html
<form action="mailto:softphoton001@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <input name="subject" type="text" />
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there isn't anything particularly wrong with the code snippet you have posted, however how mailto forms behave depends on the user's setup, especially the combination of default email client and browser. It looks like the behaviour on your computer is to open up gmail (presuming that is what you mean by a google pop up).

You might be able to change the behaviour of your setup by changing settings in your browser, but one way or another it is going to require the user to actually consent to sending the data - usually that will be by clicking send in their email client.

The following link explains this in more detail:
https://www.thoughtco.com/when-mailto-forms-dont-work-3464315

If that is not the kind of behaviour you want you may need to use an alternative approach, such as using a php script.